# Create a matrix from user input and populate it from unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, matrix

I have an assignment where I have to determine the longest adjacent sequence of strings within a user generated matrix in Python. I am a beginner and I don't know how to test my own code. I am provided with some unit tests and my question is how to add the contents of the unit test into my own code?

Any suggestions for the actual problem would also be appreciated. Want I have to do is determine the longest sequence of identical strings in the matrix (excluding diagonals).

Here is the code:

```
# accept the matrix dimensions manually

rows = int(input('Enter the number of rows:'))
cols = int(input('Enter the number of columns:'))

# initialize matrix
matrix = []
print('Enter the matrix entries:')

# populate matrix
for i in range(rows):
    a = []
    for j in range(cols):
        a.append(str(input()))
    matrix.append(a)

# print matrix
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()

# sample unit test below

3 3
R R B
G G R
R B G
```

I have figured how I can create the matrix from input and manually populate it with strings but I don't know how to directly load the data from the test.

I can reproduce the test in my own code because it is small but if I had a matrix of say 1000x1000 rows and columns I wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a unit test you have been given?

Comment: Sure, I did at the end of my post. 3x3 are the dimensions of the matrix to be tested. The letters thereafter are supposed to populate the matrix in question.